# How to get direct streaming url from this flash online streaming radio station?

Tags: flash, streaming, audio-streaming

I checked the web console and source code of http://www.allindiaradio.gov.in/Gold.htm but could not figure out

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The page mentioned in your question is playing a [**HDS**](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/hds.html) ( Adobe [HTTP Dynamic Streaming](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/hds-dynamic-streaming/pdfs/hds_datasheet.pdf) ) stream for Flash Players and a [**HLS**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming) ( Apple [HTTP Live Streaming](https://developer.apple.com/streaming/) ) stream using HTML5 video player on compatible platforms ( iOS of course, some Android versions, ... ). These streams are published using an [**FMS**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash_Media_Server) ( [Adobe Flash Media Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash_Media_Server) ) streaming server.

Both stream URLs are visible in the source code of the page and in the Network logging tab of the web browser ( google chrome in my case ) as they are two HTTP stream :

[image]

For more information about HDS and HLS you can take a look on :

- wikipedia : [Adaptive bitrate streaming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_bitrate_streaming).
- rgbnetworks.com : [Adobe HTTP Dynamic Streaming (HDS): What You Need to Know](http://www.rgbnetworks.com/blog/?p=3541).
- encoding.com : [The Definitive Guide to HDS](http://www.encoding.com/http-dynamic-streaming-hds/).
- limelight.com : [Adobe HDS…In the Limelight](http://blog.limelight.com/2012/06/adobe-hds-in-the-limelight/).
- apple.com : [Using HTTP Live Streaming](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008332-CH102-SW5).
- overdigital.com : [HLS vs. HDS – What Is the Difference and Why You Should Care](http://www.overdigital.com/2011/12/27/hls-vs-hds-what-is-the-difference-and-why-you-should-care/).
- encoding.com : [The Definitive Guide to HLS](http://www.encoding.com/http-live-streaming-hls/).

Hope that can help.

Comment: Awesome - Not sure how I missed it earlier. The first one in fact works on VLC not sure how to make user of the second one , I will go through the above docs.

Comment: Expanding the scope of the original question: is there any software which can read these URLs? By that I mean FOSS software like VLC player and not proprietary Adobe Flash etc. Further, are these URLs generally "dynamic" and change every few seconds of the stream (or does this depend on the preferences of the streaming provider)? Thirdly, if so / dynamic, would VLC etc be able to "catch on" to the changing URLs like Flash does?

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty You can use the very-nice-utility [Livestreamer](http://docs.livestreamer.io/index.html) to play a HDS or HLS stream in VLC, [MPC-HC (Media Player Classic Home Cinema)](https://mpc-hc.org/), [MPlayer](http://mplayerhq.hu/), [mpv (a fork of mplayer2 and MPlayer)](https://mpv.io), ...